Conflicting TD and TN status working in the US as a Canadian citizen
Here's the situation:

I am a Canadian citizen working in the US with TN status
My spouse is also a Canadian, and was working in the US with TN status, at Company A
My spouse was laid off from Company A earlier in 2024
To avoid having to return to Canada after the grace period, we applied for a change-of-status (I-539) to TD status for my spouse, on the basis of my TN status
Recently, my spouse was offered another job in the US at Company B, requiring again to apply for TN status
At that time, the TD change-of-status application was still pending
On the advice of company lawyers, my spouse went ahead with the TN application as normal, supported by Company B, and submitted a request to withdraw the TD application
The lawyers also said that even if the withdrawal is not processed in time, the TD application would simply be denied in favor of the new TN status with Company B
Now, we find out that USCIS (erroneously, according to company lawyers) approved the TD status for my spouse. Obviously, this is bad, because in order to continue working here, the status should be TN.

Sequence of events:

Apply for TD while in grace period of company A TN
Receive company B job
Leave US and immediately re-enter while applying for new company B TN, while TD was still pending
Receive approval of the TD application

My questions are:

As of the TD getting approved, does that invalidate my spouse's TN status associated with Company B?
It seems the easiest way to resolve this is for my spouse to travel to the border and re-enter on the correct TN status. Does this imply having to do a new TN application at the border, or simply re-entering  on the basis of the TN associated with Company B?
Is there a way to resolve this from within the US?
Even if my spouse travels to the border ASAP, some days will have passed between the TD being approved and the trip to the border, during which they'd still be working at Company B. Are these days then considered working illegally in the US on TD status?


It seems that there's an attorney working with you already, I suggest discussing this with them. The company B would be in violation employing your spouse without a status, so they're interested in resolution just as much as you.

What do you mean by your spouse "went ahead with the TN application"? Do you mean that your spouse's employer filed an I-129 for your spouse's Change of Status or Extension of Stay to TN status? If so, was this filed during the grace period? Or do you mean that your spouse left the US and re-entered into TN status?

@user102008 "went ahead" => left the US and re-entered. Upon re-entry, applied for a new TN status. The TD approval notice was received a few weeks after this re-entry on TN status. Also, at no point was my spouse beyond the grace period of the "original" (company A sponsored) TN status

@littleadv agreed, we are working with the company's attorneys, but we're in this situation despite their assurances that this situation would not arise. Asking the question here is one part of our broader effort to understand the rules and options before proceeding with the lawyers' suggested next steps

@josh_eime are you saying that the TN->TD change of status was approved after leaving the US? Generally, upon leaving the US the application is considered abandoned even if it ends up approved because of the update lag.

@littleadv Yes, the sequence of events was:

apply for TD while in grace period of company A TN.
receive company B job; leave US and immediately re-enter while applying for new company B TN, while TD was still pending.
receive approval of the TD application.
The fact that the new B-TN was received should have alerted USCIS and caused them to deny the TD, or so the lawyers said. But they still approved the TD


It takes weeks for them to get the update from CBP

Yes that's understandable, I think we got very unlucky with the timeframes here. If the approval came a bit sooner, the withdrawal was processed a bit sooner, or the company B job started a bit later or earlier, the situation could have been avoided. As you say, the lawyers probably were not wrong to suggest that USCIS would deny it, had they received the info from CBP

@josh_eime: You should update the question with the sequence of events. What was the start date of the new period of stay given by the Change of Status approval?

Updated. Start date of the (erroneous) TD was after the start of company B TN.

Adding the resolution here in case it is useful to anyone:

Lawyers confirmed that the TD application should have been considered abandoned, and should have been denied. The approval was erroneous / due to latency in CBP and USCIS communications.
However, to avoid possible future inference that my spouse worked illegally while on the (erroneously approved) TD, the employer recommended traveling to the border and returning on the TN (company B) ASAP. This is what my spouse is going to do.

